# Python regex to get numbers between optional strings

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've the following texts:

```
"Start 2 h 30 m End 3 h 20 m"
"Start 30 m End 10 m"
```

How can I extract the numbers alone so that output is

```
|Start_h|Start_m|End_h|End_m|
|-------|-------|-----|-----|
|      2|     30|    3|   20|
|    Nan|     30|  Nan|   10|
```

My attempt at this was using string extract in pandas.

`df['time'].str.extract(r'Start (\w+) h (\w+) m ')` but this doesn't give me "m" alone if "h" is not present

Comment: By texts you mean dataframe rows?

Comment: Yes. It is dataframe rows.

Comment: Can you ever have hours alone, with no minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more robust pattern:

```
TIME = r"(?:(\d+) h )?(\d+) m" # Optional hr, required min
PATTERN = "Start {} End {}".format(TIME, TIME)
df['time'].str.extract(PATTERN)
#     0   1    2   3
#0    2  30    3  20
#1  NaN  30  NaN  10
```

Note that you need a separate matching group for each column, the total of four groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import re
r = re.compile('[^0-9]*([0-9]*)')
t = 'Start 2 h 30 m End 3 h 20 m'
i = 0
while i < len(t):
    m = r.search(t, i)
    if not m:
        break
    print(m.group(1))
    i = m.end(0)
```

The code will try in loop to skip non-digit fragmets and then produce digit fragment one by one. You can't do that in "full" regex easily, as regex requires you to specify amount of numbers you expect upfront.

EDIT:
Use @accdias version, as it's better.

Comment: Because u need to update t value i guess? I did check on my comp and it works fine. In all case your version with re.findall is better (and probably as correct as possible).